# is this sentence all in the past tense? I'm struggling to write in the past tense but use active words?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, tenses, past-tense

The turf wicket at Cook reserve in Bedford has been vandalised on Sunday after diesel was poured liberally across all five cricket pitches, rendering them unusable.

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to EL&U. You might be interested in our sister site, English Language Learners; you can find it [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). It is helpful in answering basic questions.

Comment: The use of *after* seems out of place. Did the cricket pitches have diesel poured liberally across them before being vandalized?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do to make the tense of your sentence match is to use the verb *was* instead of *has been*:

The turf wicket at Cook reserve in Bedford *was* vandalised on Sunday after diesel was poured liberally across all five cricket pitches, rendering them unusable.

Now it's perfect!

Comment: It's not perfect, it's continuous. :)